# How can I transfer trophies from the same game between consoles?

Tags: achievements, ps4, ps-vita

I had earned the platinum trophy for Borderlands 2 on my PS4, and I have the same game for the PlayStation Vita.

How can I transfer my data so the platinum trophy will pop on the Vita, as well?

Comment: I can not answer your question on how to transfer the data, but transferring the data **will not unlock trophies**. Trophy unlocks are a trigger from a particular requirement being met. Even if you transfer the same stats to a different console, you will be required to forefill the trophy requirements, again. If the trophy is for, say, beating a boss, it makes it easier being already capable of fighting the boss again. But things like completion and kills won't port across as you ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is game dependent, some games share a trophy list across PS4 and PS Vita, so unlocking a trophy one one device will also unlock it on another. This is particularly true for games that are "cross-buy".

Other games have separate trophy lists, which means unlocking on one platform won't affect the other. Minecraft is an example of this, where each version has a independent list. And even though you can transfer the save data between the games, it won't retrospectively unlock the trophies you've previously unlocked.